# Get the latest of each element of a Pandas DataFrame, with range indexing and a date column?

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause, dataframe, restrict

I have a sample DataFrame as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('foo', datetime.date(2014, 10, 1)), 
                        ('foo', datetime.date(2014, 10, 2)), 
                        ('bar', datetime.date(2014, 10, 3)), 
                        ('bar', datetime.date(2014, 10, 1))], 
                  columns=('name', 'date'))
```

which looks like this:

```
  name        date
0  foo  2014-10-01
1  foo  2014-10-02
2  bar  2014-10-03
3  bar  2014-10-01
```

I want to restrict the dataframe to just the last incident of each element in the name column, how do I do this?

I could awkwardly (at least I think it would be awkward) construct a boolean Series object to do this and pass it to the DataFrame's `__getitem__`, like this:

```
pd[latest_name]
```

How do I most elegantly get the latest entry for each `name` element?

Comment: Hmmm... two upvotes, two down. I wonder why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coworker just had a very similar question to this.

With a DataFrame object like this:

```
  name        date
0  foo  2014-10-01
1  foo  2014-10-02
2  bar  2014-10-03
3  bar  2014-10-01
```

You can sort by the date and then drop the duplicates, keeping the last ones like this:

```
last = df.sort(columns=('date',)).drop_duplicates(cols=('name',), take_last=True)
# note cols is deprecated in more recent versions of pandas,
# and you should use subset='name' if available to you
```

and `last` is now:

```
  name        date
1  foo  2014-10-02
2  bar  2014-10-03

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

But it may be preferable to set the date as the index, if we can drop the old indexes, and then just sort by the index:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.sort_index() # inplace=True is deprecated, so must assign
```

`df` now returns:

```
           name
date           
2014-10-01  foo
2014-10-01  bar
2014-10-02  foo
2014-10-03  bar
```

Now to just take the last elements:

```
last_elements_frame = df.drop_duplicates(take_last=True)
```

and `last_elements_frame` is now:

```
           name
date           
2014-10-02  foo
2014-10-03  bar
```